# XCode UI Builder not showing blue lines

Tags: ios, xcode

I am very new to IOS development and starts working on xcode. In its UI Builder I am not able to see any blue lines when I am dragging it to place in any portion of the screen. I have already selected Editor>Canvas and selected Show constraints, Show Bound Rectangles, Show Device Bezels. I have selected Use Auto Layout & Use Trait Variations as well.

[image]

These kind of blue lines I want when I am dragging button:

[image]

Comment: Which blue lines are you talking about? You can also enable "Show Layout Rectangles" for more blue lines.

Comment: @Alper thanks for your reply. That blue line, if you are dragging your button on UI Builder screen, then it will tell show blue lines, for example it will give you blue lines, if you place button in center of the screen. Plx check my updated question, I am placing one screenshot there, which I want in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are Guides and you want to enable Snap to Guides like here.

[image]

Comment: thanks alot, it solved my problem. Yes exactly I want this exact option. It is showing me guide lines now.